# How to use time.time() in a SQLAlchemy hybrid_property?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a column `FOO: Mapped[int]` that stores some timestamps. I want to compare these timestamps against the current timestamp with `time.time()`, with something like `where(table.FOO < time.time())`. I want this in a hybrid_property. However, according to the documentation, you can't put arbitrary functions in a hybrid_property.

Would this work, regardless?

```
 @hybrid_property
    def bar(self):
       return self.FOO < time.time()
```